# What if statement about claims with effective filing date on or after March 16, 2013 is not submitted in time

Tags: examination, pre-aia, aia, march-16-2013, transitional-application

CFR 1.78(a)(6) says that, if a non-provisional application claims the benefit of a provisional application filed before March 16, 2013 and contains, or contained at any time, a claim that has an effective filing date on or after March 16, 2013, the applicant must file a statement to that effect within a certain time period.  What happens if the statement is not filed within the stipulated time period?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you have a transitional application for which you did not timely provide the '1.78 statement' required by [37 C.F.R. 1.78](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9020-appx-r.html#aia_d0e320662) and [MPEP 2159.04](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2159.html#ch2100_d222e3_140d7_1bb).

Since the application data sheet (ADS) form PTO/AIA/14 includes a checkbox for making the statement under 37 C.F.R. 1.78, you *may* still be able to make the statement by filing a corrected/updated ADS. See [MPEP 601.05(a) pertaining to 37 C.F.R. 1.76(b)(5) and 37 C.F.R. 1.76(c)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s601.html#ch600_d1ff5e_1ae97_96).

Also see [MPEP 211.04](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s211.html#ch200_d1ff71_24f8b_4a), the second paragraph deals with delayed 35 U.S.C. 119(e) benefit claims.

If you do not provide the statement at all: your application may be examined according to pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102-103 when your application should be examined under AIA 35 U.S.C. 102. As a result, the examiner may not apply (valid) prior art references available under AIA 35 U.S.C. 102 but not available under pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102-103.